# Want to delay the popover show in bootstrap while using manual trigger option

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, jquery-hover

I am using popover plugin for showing hovercard and i am using ajax for getting the username data from the file. I am using this code:

```
jQ('.username').popover({ 
            html : true,
            trigger: 'manual',
            placement: function (context, source) {
                var position = jQ(source).position();
                if (position.left > 515) {
                  return "left";
                }
                if (position.left < 515) {
                  return "right";
                }
                if (position.top < 110){
                  return "bottom";
                }
                return "top";
            },
            //delay: {show: 700},
            content: function() {
                // Get link where user hover the username.
                var view_user_link = jQ(this).attr('href').split('/');
                // Get userid.
                var userid = view_user_link[2];
                var login_userid = getCookie('userid');
                if(global_hash.perm_view_profiles || login_userid == userid) {
                    // Sent AJAX request to get user information to show in hovercard.
                    if(!jQ('#content_'+userid).html()) {
                        var obj = this;
                        jQ.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/register',
                            data: {'action':'show_hovercard', 'userid':userid},
                            success: function (response) {
                                // Show hovercard data into tooltip.
                                jQ('a.username').attr('title','');
                                jQ('#hover_card_content').append(response);
                                return jQ('#content_'+userid).html();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // If AJAX request already sent from the user on the same page then data get from the page.
                        jQ('a.username').attr('title','');
                        return jQ('#content_'+userid).html();
                    }
                } else {
                    // If user does't permission to view another user profile then show title.
                    jQ('a.username').attr('title','View profile');
                }   
            }

        }).on("mouseenter", function() {
            var _this = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                jQ(_this).popover("show");
                jQ(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                    jQ('.username').popover('hide');
                });
            }, 400);
        }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            var _this = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (!jQ(".popover:hover").length) {
                    if(!jQ(_this).is(':hover')) {
                        jQ(_this).popover('hide');
                    }
                }
            }, 200);
        });
```

Please help me how can I delay the popover show because first time its not showing the data on hovering the username link thats because I am using ajax for fetching data

Comment: Hi, Please help me on this. I am stuck to this issue

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable outside the ajax call, on success feed whatever you want to pass to the popover, and on complete enable the popover with content

```
     var popOverContent;
     $.getJSON("url?id=" + obj.id + ", function (data) {
            popOverContent = BuildPopOverDataContent(data.Title, data.Description);
        })
        .always(function () {                    
            EnableHelpPopOver(obj.id, popOverContent);      
            $(jqObjId).trigger("mouseover");  //This will trigger the popover to show
        });   

function BuildPopOverDataContent(Title, Description) {
   return "<h2>Some Content</h2>";
}


function EnableHelpPopOver(container, popOverContent) {
    var objId = "#" + container;        
    $(objId).popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: objId,
        placement: 'top',
        delay: {
            show: "500",
            hide: "100"
        },
        content: popOverContent
    });
}
```